# How can I use the VisualStudio 10 Debugger to inspect the underlying nHibernate (3.1) criteria text

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, nhibernate, visual-studio-debugging, nhibernate-3

Under Windows I have code similar to the following:

```
var active_ids = QueryOver.Of<Members>()
.Where(m => m.HasAccess);
```

I have found that if I break the debugger after this line and type
**?active_ids.criteria** the following is displayed:

```
{IsApproved = True}
```

and

```
var namematch = Restrictions.Disjunction();
namematch.Add(Restrictions.Where<Members>(m => m.FirstName.IsInsensitiveLike(name.AsStartsWith())));
namematch.Add(Restrictions.Where<Members>(m => m.LastName.IsInsensitiveLike(name.AsStartsWith())));
namematch.Add(Restrictions.Where<Members>(m => m.LastName.IsInsensitiveLike(("-" + name).AsContains())));
```

I have found that if I break the debugger after this line and type
**?namematch.criteria** the following is displayed:

```
Count = 3
    [0]: {FirstName ilike bak%}
    [1]: {LastName ilike bak%}
    [2]: {LastName ilike %-bak%}
```

However, when I have a very complicated query, similar to:

```
var matchQuery = session.QueryOver<Member_Graph>()
.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(vg => vg.MemberId).In(memberlist)
.Where(approved_members)
.JoinQueryOver<Trainers_Graph>(t => t.trainers)
.Where(namematch)
.Select(t => t.trainers);
```

However, when I type **?matchQuery**

'NHibernate...' does not contain a definition for 'criteria' and no extension method 'criteria' accepting a first argument of type ... could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So, using the Visual Studio Debugger, how can I list the full criteria that nHibernate generates for matchQuery

Comment: what does it display for `?matchQuery.RootCriteria`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session.QueryOver() is just a wrapper for a ICriteria which has the nice ability to be displayed as a string. To access the underlying Criteria use `matchQuery.RootCriteria`

Comment: Is there an easy way to see the entire sql that will be generated, including the tables, etc?

Comment: see http://www.davesquared.net/2008/01/viewing-sql-generated-by-nhibernate.html for logging sql

Comment: Yes, I know about the logging options, I was looking for something that would display directly in the debugger